# Are makeLog instruction functions opcodes or not?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, opcode

The following code snippet is a constituent piece of the `instructions.go` file, where our lieblings `opCodes` all live.

```
// make log instruction function
func makeLog(size int) executionFunc {
    return func(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
        topics := make([]common.Hash, size)
        mStart, mSize := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
        for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
            topics[i] = common.BigToHash(stack.pop())
        }

        d := memory.Get(mStart.Int64(), mSize.Int64())
        evm.StateDB.AddLog(&types.Log{
            Address: contract.Address(),
            Topics:  topics,
            Data:    d,
            // This is a non-consensus field, but assigned here because
            // core/state doesn't know the current block number.
            BlockNumber: evm.BlockNumber.Uint64(),
        })

        evm.interpreter.intPool.put(mStart, mSize)
        return nil, nil
    }
}

// make push instruction function
func makePush(size uint64, pushByteSize int) executionFunc {
    return func(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
        codeLen := len(contract.Code)

        startMin := codeLen
        if int(*pc+1) < startMin {
            startMin = int(*pc + 1)
        }

        endMin := codeLen
        if startMin+pushByteSize < endMin {
            endMin = startMin + pushByteSize
        }

        integer := evm.interpreter.intPool.get()
        stack.push(integer.SetBytes(common.RightPadBytes(contract.Code[startMin:endMin], pushByteSize)))

        *pc += size
        return nil, nil
    }
}

// make push instruction function
func makeDup(size int64) executionFunc {
    return func(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
        stack.dup(evm.interpreter.intPool, int(size))
        return nil, nil
    }
}

// make swap instruction function
func makeSwap(size int64) executionFunc {
    // switch n + 1 otherwise n would be swapped with n
    size += 1
    return func(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
        stack.swap(int(size))
        return nil, nil
    }
```

The question is, are these `make log instruction functions` themselves opcodes?

If they are- why are they not called as such?

If not- what are they doing living in the file with all of the `opCodes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I've fully understood your question, but here are my observations...

The opcodes handled by the four `make*` functions you list differ from the other EVM opcodes in that they are each part of wider opcode families:

- `makeLog()` handles opcodes `LOG0` thru `LOG4`
- `makePush()` handles opcodes `PUSH1` thru `PUSH32`
- `makeDup()` handles opcodes `DUP1` thru `DUP16`
- `makeSwap()` handles opcodes `SWAP1` thru `SWAP16`

This differs from the other functions in the file, each of which handles only a single opcode, along with its stack operands.

In addition, the `LOG*` opcodes are particularly unusual since each one consumes a different number of stack operands: `LOG0` consumes 2, `LOG4` consumes 6.  So this needs to be dealt with as well.

In the end, the function returned by each of the `make*()` meta-functions will perform the work of a single opcode, and is therefore on an equal footing with the other functions in the file.